# why lifecycle callback does not get called?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

i am learning developing using vue js.

i want to be able to use the lifecycle callbacks. As shown in the code posted bewlo, in `App.vue`, i implemented the `onMounted` callback. But when i run the code, i do not receive the message in the `console.log`

would you please tell me how to modify the code so i can receive the log message stated in the `onMounted`

**note**: i am using compositional API

**App.vue**:

```
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
  <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
import { createApp, onMounted } from 'vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
}

createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')

onMounted(()=>{
    console.log("onMounted");
})

</script>
```

**hello world.vue**:

```
<template>

  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="app">
  <button @click="count++">
    Count is: {{ count }}
  </button>
</div>

</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's incorrect to use createApp in App.vue, it's incorrect to use onMounted outside setup function. Generally you shouldn't have anything besides imports outside export default when you use <script> syntax in .vue. Consider following the official guides.

Comment: Are you using SSR with Vue? If so, then component lifecycle events and callbacks aren't raised/called in SSR scenarios [according to the docs](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html).

Comment: @Dai no i am not using ssr

Comment: @EstusFlask can you please provide an example!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Composition API, you need to add 'setup' to the 'script' tag, for example:

```js
<script setup>

import { onMounted } from 'vue'

// lifecycle hooks
onMounted(() => {
  console.log('onMounted')
})

</script>
```

Here is the official [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html#composition-api).

Additionally, I recommend creating a Vue template using [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-vite-project).